# Self Signed Certificate for localhost

Tags: ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate

[My Machine localhost image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TGEd.png)

I have created a self signed apache certificate for my localhost but I'm getting red https ( Not Secure connection ).

How would I turn it into green https.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Self-signed certs aren't trusted by definition.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a self-signed certificate, then the browser by default will not accept as a valid one, because the certificate isn't trusted by an certificate authority;

Moreover, you can deploy one *free* from Let's Encrypt, e.g;

Here is a [link](https://certbot.eff.org/) from Certbot - It is an easy way to deploy on your server.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Maybe it can help you
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: I tried but it is still showing not secure connection.